# How to create live tiles in PowerPoint 2013 for wireframing?

Tags: windows-8, powerpoint, user-experience, wireframe, powerpoint-2013

I am trying to create wire frames for Windows 8 store apps for initial prototyping.

I have read that we can create live tiles in PowerPoint and it is demonstrated once in a [keynote adress](http://www.winrumors.com/microsoft-flaunts-metro-style-powerpoint-live-tiles-video/).

Does anybody know how to implement live tiles in PPT?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to create? Just an image or one/some ofthe animations too? If so, which?

Comment: This is how it should be [imgur](http://imgur.com/DcwQ0Ih,0cwrSLB#0).The first image should up and tile should change to 2nd image later just like live tiles

Comment: There are a large number of tile templates supported. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx I don't know which your image is supposed to represent

Comment: Also, if you're wire framing then there should be no need for animation. Wire frames are static. Are you actually creating a mockup?

Comment: thanks for the link .I wanted to know if we could animate the tiles in powerpoint just like in actual app?

Comment: i had planned to create prototype in blend ,but due to time constraints i am falling back on PPT. Also this is a business presentation , so a PPT is preferred .I am really curious how MS demonstrated live tiles in PPT in the presentation link above.